# The module "taggableComplete" is not enabled

Tags: plugins, symfony1, tags, doctrine

I'm trying to add the tag widget from the plugin **sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin**

I've added "_tag" to my configuration.yml, and in _tag.php I wrote :

```
<?php include_component('taggableComplete','tagWidget', array('object' => $form->getObject())) ?>
```

But all I get now is the following error :

> "The module "taggableComplete" is not
>   enabled"

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable modules you want to use after installing a plugin.

*tagWidget* component is defined in *taggableComplete* module. As it's a module from the plugin you have explicitly enable it.

You can do it in your application's *settings.yml* file:

```
all:
  .settings:
    enabled_modules: [default, taggableComplete]
```